# How to add software RAID-1 to an existing non-RAID system?

Tags: 14.04, grub2, raid, mdadm

I couldn't find any tutorials for converting a non-RAID system (Ubuntu 14.04 in my case) into a **disk-level** RAID-1 system after installing a second disk (`/dev/sdb`)

Is the following correct?

```
sgdisk --replicate=/dev/sdb /dev/sda # copy partition table
sgdisk -G /dev/sdb # randomize IDs
mdadm --create /dev/md --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda missing
mdadm /dev/md -a /dev/sdb
echo "DEVICE /dev/sda /dev/sdb" >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf # is this needed?
mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf  
dpkg-reconfigure mdadm
```

Do I need to do anything about `grub`, or will it be copied together with the rest of `/dev/sda`?

(**Extra**: I found a tutorial here: http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/setting-up-raid-on-existing/, but it advocates copying data manually from a live partition, which seems wrong (data race), and also it applies `mdadm` at the partition level, while I want to mirror the whole disk)

Comment: I would first ask how many disks you have with the same size (Need at least 2). Where is the boot part of Ubuntu (in sda, sdb, sdc...). In case you have only one disk, then how many partitions have you setup (in case you want a RAID 1 using only one physical disk but you will loose the whole point of raid1) which have the same size. Also you do not need to do anything to grub until we can understand what you actually have and how it is configured right now. Other than that, excellent question.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado I had one disk (/dev/sda), then added another, which I'm trying to configure into a mirror. The disks are physically identical.